# MCP23S17 Interrupt Issue

Tags: interrupts, microchip, gpio

I am having issues with interrupt setup on MCP23S17. Not able to set up the INTB line properly. I have an external 10K pull up resistor connected to the line and 3 input buttons connected to GPB0 - GPB2.

I tried setting the INT line as Open Drain. Still I read 0 on INTB. Also tried setting up the line as Push Pull with Active Low interrupt polarity. Still get a 0.

I am able to control GPA as an output port just fine.

Below is my code

```
#define MCP23S17_OPCODE_WRITE   0x40
#define MCP23S17_OPCODE_READ    0x41

#define MCP23S17_IOCONA     0x0A
#define MCP23S17_IOCONB     0x0B

#define MCP23S17_IODIRA     0x00
#define MCP23S17_IODIRB     0x01

#define MCP23S17_GPIOA      0x12
#define MCP23S17_GPIOB      0x13

#define MCP23S17_OLATA      0x14
#define MCP23S17_OLATB      0x15

#define MCP23S17_GPINTENB   0x05
#define MCP23S17_DEFVALB    0x07
#define MCP23S17_INTCONB    0x09
#define MCP23S17_INTFB      0x0f




void EXTERNAL_MCP23S17_Init(void)
{   
//IOCONA (DEFAULT)
//SET MIRROR = 0
s_external_mcp23s17_write_reg(MCP23S17_IOCONA, 0x00);

//IOCONB
//SET MIRROR = 0
//SET ODR = 1 (INTB PIN IN AS OPEN DRAIN MODE)
s_external_mcp23s17_write_reg(MCP23S17_IOCONB, 0x04);

//SET GPA AS OUTPUT
s_external_mcp23s17_write_reg(MCP23S17_IODIRA, 0x00);

//SET GPB AS INPUT (DEFAULT)
s_external_mcp23s17_write_reg(MCP23S17_IODIRB, 0x07);

//SET GPOA INITIAL VALUES
s_external_mcp23s17_write_reg(MCP23S17_GPIOA, 0x27);
s_external_mcp23s17_write_reg(MCP23S17_OLATA, 0x27);

//ENABLE INTERRUPT ON CHANGE FOR GPB0 - GPB2
s_external_mcp23s17_write_reg(MCP23S17_GPINTENB, 0x07);
//SET GPB DEFAULT COMPARE REGISTER FOR INTERRUPTS
s_external_mcp23s17_write_reg(MCP23S17_DEFVALB, 0xFF);
//SET GPB INTERRUPT CONTROL REGISTER
//COMPARE PIN VALUE AGAINST DEFAULT VALUE
s_external_mcp23s17_write_reg(MCP23S17_INTCONB, 0xFF);
SEGGER_RTT_printf(0, MODULE_NAME_EXTERNAL_MCP23S17"%s OK\n", __FUNCTION__);
}
```

Not sure what I am missing here. Have checked the datasheet and I don't think I've missed anything

Answer (score 1):

Constant 0 on INTB pin means that the interrupt is active (in both configurations, active-low push-pull and open-drain).

It is not clear where do you have 10k resistor, on INTB pin or on GPB0 - GPB2 pins. If you don't have external pull-ups on GPB pins, you should enable internal pull-ups through `GPPU` register.

You should also clear the interrupt by reading `INTCAP` or `GPIO` register.

> The interrupt remains active until the INTCAP or GPIO register is read.

[3.6.4 INTERRUPT OPERATION](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001952C.pdf#G1.1139398)